# How to seperate object data into each sheet of CSV file for Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I need your help or advice to loop my data below figure1 to CSV file which can be separated by DeviceA and DeviceB in sheet of excel file.

Let's see example file details that the data will be separated by sheet ProductDay1 and ProductDay2 via http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/48/

**Figure1**

```
var dataObj = 
{ deviceA:
   [ [ 'DeviceA' ],
     [ 'Date/Time', 'smokeSensor', 'fireSensor' ],
     [ '01/05/19 0001', '200', '700' ],
     [ '01/05/19 0002', '300', '750' ],
     [ '02/05/19 0001', '20', '780' ],
     [ '02/05/19 0002', '30', '630' ]],
  deviceB:
   [ [ 'DeviceB' ],
     [ 'Date/Time', 'smokeSensor', 'fireSensor' ],
     [ '01/06/19 0001', '100', '600' ],
     [ '01/06/19 0002', '110', '522' ],
     [ '02/06/19 0001', '120' ],
     [ '02/06/19 0002', '130' ] ] 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issues are.. does the above code work?

Comment: Its work but that's not my point. The problem is how to get CSV file by separate DeviceA and DeviceB to each sheet in excel file.

I want a CSV file which separate details by sheet like this http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/48/

Comment: an excel file is a zip file - inspect it or check for exceljs library - but basically not as trivial as making a csv

Comment: Hi -  i mean i can read your fiddle, but its hard - it will be nice if your try to wrap actions into functions of about 4 to 5 lines and use expressive names - else the the reader has to use his mind compiler doing exactly this. before he is actually able to assist ;) thx

Comment: So, That means I have no way to do ?. Is that possible to make some function to convert my dataObj to xls or anything can open with excel by separately DeviceA and DeviceB to each sheet of one file.